# Phone restarts when plugged ito PC

Tags: usb, usb-debugging, reboot

When i plug in my phone to my pc, my pc installs the drivers then my phone just restarts. And after that, my phone screen won't turn off

Comment: Why the usb-debugging tag? Does this only happen when USB Debugging is enabled? Does it only do it on one computer and USB port, or on every computer and port? This sounds kind of like the USB voltage is too high or low (guessing, but a bad power adapter with too high voltage can show similar symptoms).

Comment: It happens when it's both on and off and on my pc only. I'm using a stock usb charger wire for it.